# Visual Studio hangs on localhost - web form - JSNLog with Elmah

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, elmah, jsnlog

I recently added jsnlog for elmah to a fairly large asp.net web form.  Currently I'm testing on my localhost, and have only added logging on one page.  I'm noticing that after I access that page, when I click in the Visual Studio (2015) IDE it freezes up for a minute or two.  Accessing any other page in the web application doesn't cause the freezing issue.

I previously created a stand-alone version of the jsnlog demo for elmah to help familiarize myself, and do not have the problem of Visual Studio freezing.

My concern is that the freezing isn't just Visual Studio acting up or being on localhost, but I'm unsure where to start troubleshooting.